# implementing wordpress theme customizer in title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress theme customizer. I am developing a theme. In my theme, i want it to be dynamic in changing the title for the admin dashboard easily manage my custom made theme. I am really a beginner, my question is very simple.How do i change the title of my site using the theme customizer? . sorry guys for this question  but still i am a beginner in wordpress CMS. I've read any tutorials and i came up with this code from my functions php file. I dont know how to implement what i've got from the tutorial that ive read

here is my functions.php :

```
function change_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {
$wp_customize->add_section( 'mysite_content_options_section' , array(
        'title'      => __( 'Content Options', 'mysite' ),
        'priority'   => 100,
    ) );
}
add_action('customize_register','change_theme_customizer');
```

from my header to display my title that doesn't work here it is:

```
<title>
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'mysite' ) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" id="site-logo" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'mysite' ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    No Site title
<?php endif; ?>
    </title>
```

Sorry guys i'm totally new in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate dynamic theme customization you can follow up this link and it looks pretty easy so that you can make up dynamic title as and when needed by you in WordPress Admin Dashboard.

Reference:

https://perishablepress.com/how-to-generate-perfect-wordpress-title-tags-without-a-plugin/

Comment: hello sir, do i need to add some code in implementing this in my functions.php ?

Comment: Hello sir, i've copied his code from the title and when i go to search it display my title with = Search for " the value of what ive search" ..

Comment: sir can you give me another article in changing site icon? :) thank you very much

Comment: Sure will let you know on this asap :)

Comment: Thanks.. Glad to help you.